# iOS: best file type to quickly read data from?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have  large .plist file, which I download from a server, with a couple of thousand dictionaries contained within, each with 11 attributes.

My question is:

**What is the best file type/structure to store this data in, in order to quickly read it later on?**

I am currently using a binary plist format, however it still takes a substantial amount of time. This is because I also need to read several attributes of the data contained within and display it also.

Comment: Are the attributes the same in each dictionary? It sounds like you need a database. Look into [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org).

Comment: @bdesham Yes. So you suggest converting the .plist into core data after downloading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation it's better to go for core data. 
i found [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) is really helpful when you are dealing with core data.